# Lewis structure of XeF2 that comes closer to reality?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, resonance, lewis-structure

Meanwhile, the hypervalency of Xe in XeF<sub>2</sub> is explained by the 3c4e bond, where the p orbitals of the 3 atoms overlap to form a delocalized system of 3 MO's in which 4 electrons (two from the Xe p orbital and one each from the p orbitals of the F atoms). This leads to a bond order of 1/2 per Xe-F group.

Obviously, the lewis representation that can be found everywhere on the Internet cannot be correct:

[image]

That would indicate a bond order of 1 per F-Xe Group, not 1/2.

As far as I know, resonance drawings are used to indicate delocalized bonds, so they also represent bond orders of 1/2. Shouldn't XeF<sub>2</sub> then be represented as a lewis diagram as follows:

[image]

And I also wonder what orbitals are those 3 lone pairs at Xe? s,p,p? Or 3 sp<sup>2</sup> hybride orbitals (which would make more sense for the geometry but less sense because hybridisation just makes sense for bonds)?

Comment: Lewis structures are not intended to be accurate representations of the electronic structure of molecules. They follow conventional rules that make the drawings simple, but informative. According to those conventions, expanded octets are preferred *in the drawing* for elements larger than fluorine, whether or not they are truly hypervalent.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! Btw. what do you mean by "whether or not they are truly hypervalent"? Are there compounds that are/ aren't truly hypervalent?

Comment: @Andrew Or more precisely, are there really any that *are truly* hypervalent? https://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=2599

Comment: @Andrew Maybe I should consider hypervalency as a synonym for hypercoordination?

Comment: sure, if that helps you understand it.

Comment: Hypervalency is essentially a concept that can only work within the framework of expanded octets. In that framework multicentre bonds do not exist. So hypercoordination is indeed a better term for what is at play here. Even though it is used as a synonym often, I would actually advise against this. However, you can easily substitute the latter for any intends and purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Just after XeF<sub>2</sub> was discovered, D. F. Smith published a short communication [Xenon Difluoride](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1733476) *J. Chem. Phys.* 38, 270 (1963) mentioning the electronic structure of your second drawing.

Smith conducted infrared spectroscopy of XeF<sub>2</sub> and wrote:

[image]

Then C. A. Coulson published [The nature of the bonding in xenon fluorides and related molecules](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1964/JR/JR9640001442) *J. Chem. Soc.*, 1964, 1442-1454, which considered the validity of four models (plus some sub-models) of XeF<sub>2</sub> bonding.

Coulson adds more resonance structures in addition to the two mentioned by Smith, including a purely ionic F- Xe2+ F- resonance structure.

For a more recent article on the topic, see [The essential role of charge-shift bonding in hypervalent prototype XeF2](http://jupiter.chem.uoa.gr/thanost/papers/papers7/NatChem_5(2013)417.pdf) *Nature Chemistry* 5, 417–422 (2013). ([official link](https://www.nature.com/articles/nchem.1619))

Overall, ionic contributions do need to be considered.